# Error while sending STMT_PREPARE packet with mysqli Prepare

Tags: php, mysqli, cron, prepared-statement

I am running a cron job to send out emails. After the emails are sent, I update the database to mark them sent:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($q))
```

But I am getting the error: `Error while sending STMT_PREPARE packet. PID=25982;`

The error shows the code being executed and that there are approx 50 integer ids in the `IN` clause for the table's primary key:

prepare('UPDATE emailqueue SET datesent='2015-08-28 19:35:49' WHERE emailqueueid IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)')

I am on a shared server so have limited ability to change mysql settings.

Aside from reducing the number of `?` in the `IN` statement, anything else I can do? It will work for smaller amounts of data. Is this really considered a large amount of data for it to choke on?

From phpinfo

```
mysqli
MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 15d5c781cfcad91193dceae1d2cdd127674ddb3e $ 
Active Persistent Links     0 
Inactive Persistent Links   0 
Active Links    0 

Directive   Local Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On
mysqli.allow_persistent On
mysqli.default_host no value
mysqli.default_port 3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value
mysqli.default_socket   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off
```

---

** UPDATE **
The solution for me was to set the session variable using the following:

```
mysqli->query("SET session wait_timeout=28800");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase these values in your `/etc/my.cnf`

```
max_allowed_packet
wait_timeout
```

Comment: Your answer would work if I had control over the server. Because it is a shared host, using `mysqli->query("SET session wait_timeout=28800")` was my solution. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem - after I'd added a `sleep(60);` line to my file whilst doing some testing.

The underlying problem is that the mysqli connection had timed out. You can check that with this test:

```
if ($mysqli->ping()) {
    // Connected.
}
else {
    // Not connected.
}
```

To fix your problem, you may be able to increase the mysqli timeout value (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php , for example).

And/or, if you find there is no connection (i.e., by using the above code before you attempt to do a mysqli operation), you should be able to re-initiate the connection. (Before doing this, it ***may*** be necessary/safest to call `$mysqli->close();` first just to make sure the old resource is properly released.)

Comment: Thanks for your input. The solution for me was to set `mysqli->query("SET session wait_timeout=28800")`. Seeing as its an old post, I'll update my question to reflect this.